# With json4s how to add field on-the-fly during serialization

Tags: json, scala, serialization, json4s

I have a case class which has several `DateTime` fields. While using `json4s` to serialize it I want to serialize each of these fields as 2 separated fields - one in formatted datetime string and the other one in unix timestamp.

So for example the case class is:

```
case class Event {
    name: String,
    start: DateTime
}
```

For an object:

```
val event = Event("foo", DateTime.now)
```

I want the serialized json string to be:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "start": "2014-04-01T09:00:00+0000",
    "startUnixtime": 1396342800
}
```

I've tried `FieldSerializer` and `CustomSerializer` but couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work:

```
import org.json4s.CustomSerializer
import org.json4s.JsonDSL.WithBigDecimal._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization._

object EventSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Event](format =>
  ( PartialFunction.empty,
    {
      case Event(name, start) =>
        ( "name" -> name ) ~
        ( "start" -> stringFormat(start) ) ~
        ( "startUnixtime" -> unixtimeFormat(start) )
    }))
```

as long as you have methods to serialize start to your date format and to unixtime format.

Does this solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks - this does the trick. However if I have a long list of properties and only want to change few of them that could produce some ugly codes...

Comment: If you want to avoid ugly code you can write something like this: 
case event: Event => Extraction.decompose(event)(DefaultFormats) merge render(( "startUnixtime" -> unixtimeFormat(start) ))
and import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._